# Как переименовать все записи в определенном столбце .tsv файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть .tsv файл в котором содержатся данные в виде таблицы. Мне необходимо изменить в определенном столбце все записи. На пример:
Исходная таблица:

```
| / | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  
|-- |-- |-- |-- |-- |-- |  
| a |x  |x  |y  |x  |x  |  
| b |x  |x  |y  |x  |x  |  
| c |x  |x  |y  |x  |x  |
```

Желаемый результат:
В 3 столбце изменить все записи на x

```
| / | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  
|-- |-- |-- |-- |-- |-- |  
| a |x  |x  |x  |x  |x  |  
| b |x  |x  |x  |x  |x  |  
| c |x  |x  |x  |x  |x  |
```

**Дополнительный вопрос №1**

Как сделать так чтобы код, представленный ниже, не создавал дополнительный столбец вначале уже готовой таблицы?

**Дополнительный вопрос №2**

Как в код, представленный ниже, добавить условие?
На пример:
если имя в 3 столбце = у, то меняем на х, а если имя = t, то меняем на z

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `Pandas` можно пользоваться или вручную нужно всё?

Comment: Большая таблица, необходимо автоматически как нибудь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas | conda install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t")
df["3"] = "x"
df.to_csv(filename, sep="\t", index=False)
```

---

Если имя столбца заранее неизвестно и вы хотите поменять значения в третьем по счету столбце, тогда вместо `df["3"] = "x"` нужно будет сделать так:

```
df.iloc[:, 2] = "x"  # нумерация в Python и Pandas/Numpy начинается с нуля
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую этот способ

Comment: MaxU ,можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как сделать так чтобы код, который вы скинули выше, не создавал в таблице новый индексный столбец?

Comment: @Baldr, исправил ответ ...